# Cannot convert custom data type to string?

Tags: java, string, serialization, custom-data-attribute, custom-data-type

I am developing a library system using java serialization.when i implementing the book issue part, i need to store details of book and details of the member.

i used "issueNewBook" method for that. that method belongs to "Book" class.so when i called this method it has a atribute "libraryMember member" and this return the member id.

after i called this method it says string cannot to convert libraryMember ?
I don't know how to fix this.I tried everything I know.Your help is so important at this time.Thanks in advance.

Library member class :

```
public class libraryMember implements Serializable{


    String userType;
    String username;
    String password;
    String confirmPassword;
    private String name;
    public int memberNumber;
    private SetOfBooks currentLoans = new SetOfBooks();
    private static int memberCount = 0;


    public libraryMember() {

        userType=null;
        username=null;
        password=null;
        confirmPassword=null;
    }


public libraryMember(String aName){

name= aName;
memberNumber = memberCount++;
currentLoans = new SetOfBooks();

}

    @Override
    public String toString(){

return Integer.toString(memberNumber) + " " + name;


}
    public void borrowBook(Book aBook){

    currentLoans.addBook(aBook);
    aBook.setBorrower(this);

    }
    public String getUserType(){

    return this.userType;
    }

    public Object getName() {
         return this.username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }


    public String getConfirmPassword() {
        return this.confirmPassword;
    }

    public void singUp(Object userType, String username, String password) {

        this.userType = (String) userType;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;

    }

}
```

Book class :

```
public class Book implements Serializable{

    public String title;
    public String author;
    public String publisher;
    public String isbn;
    public int noOfCopies;
    private libraryMember borrower = null;
    private static int bookCount = 0;
    private int accessionNumber;
    public String Issuedate;
    public String returnDate;

    public Book(String name){

    title = name;
    accessionNumber = bookCount++;

    }

   public void addNewBook(int bookID, String title, String author,String publisher,String isbn,int noOfCopies) {

        this.accessionNumber = bookID;
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.publisher = publisher;
        this.isbn=isbn;
        this.noOfCopies=noOfCopies;

    }

   public void issueNewBook(int bookID,String title,libraryMember member,String issuedDate,String returnDate)
   {
   this.accessionNumber= bookID;
   this.title= title;
   this.borrower=member;
   this.Issuedate = issuedDate;
   this.returnDate=returnDate;


   }
    public int getBookID()
    {
    return accessionNumber+1;

    }
    public String getBookName()
    {

    return title;
    }

    void setBorrower(libraryMember theBorrower){

    borrower = theBorrower;

    }

    libraryMember geMember(){

    return borrower;

    }

}
```

Book issue button action :

// TODO add your handling code here:

```
 ArrayList<Book> bookList = new ArrayList();

        int flag = 0;
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("issuedBook.dat");
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

            Book book;
            while ((book = (Book) ois.readObject()) != null) {
                if (book.getBookName().equals(issue_BookNameArea.getText())) {
                    flag = 1;
                    break;
                }
                bookList.add(book);
            }
            ois.close();
            fis.close();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {


        }
        catch (EOFException e) {
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex2) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        if (flag == 0) {
            //write to file only if name doesn't exist
          Book bk = new Book(getName());

            String s = issue_BookNameArea.getText();


      libraryMember member = null;

            bk.issueNewBook((Integer.parseInt(issue_BookIdField.getText())),issue_BookNameArea.getText(),issue_MemberID.getText(), issueDate_dateChooser.getText(), returndaateField.getText());

            bookList.add(bk);
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos;
                ObjectOutputStream oos;
                fos = new FileOutputStream("newMember.dat");
                oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

                Book b;
                Iterator i = bookList.iterator();
                while (i.hasNext()) {
                    b = (Book) i.next();
                    oos.writeObject(b);
                    oos.flush();
                }

                fos.close();
                oos.close();
               // dispose();


            } catch (IOException e) {
            }

        }
```

}

Problem contain method :

bk.issueNewBook((Integer.parseInt(issue_BookIdField.getText())),issue_BookNameArea.getText(),issue_MemberID.getText(), issueDate_dateChooser.getText(), returndaateField.getText());

Error come from :

issue_MemberID.getText()

Error :

String cannot be converted to libraryMember

Comment: The error is quite self-explanatory: the `issueNewBook` method expects a `libraryMember` as its third argument but you are passing a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
bk.issueNewBook((Integer.parseInt(issue_BookIdField.getText())),issue_BookNameArea.getText(),issue_MemberID.getText(), issueDate_dateChooser.getText(), returndaateField.getText());
```

Try creating a new `libraryMember` object with the string from `getText()` (since you already have a constructor defined that takes a string) and pass that as the third paramater:

```
bk.issueNewBook((Integer.parseInt(issue_BookIdField.getText())),issue_BookNameArea.getText(),new libraryMember(issue_MemberID.getText()), issueDate_dateChooser.getText(), returndaateField.getText());
```